# How do we measure the total time taken to complete a flow across two different java applications?

Tags: java, performance, java-8

I have two different java applications integrated with each other. Consider them A (will be running on EDGE) & B(Running on cloud). Suppose if I receive some data in A and then it sends it to B to complete some processing and persist, how best can we measure the total time taken to complete the flow ?. I was actually relying on the log time to do this. I also went through **System.nanoTime & milliseconds** methods. I understand the wallclock time may not be synced with one another always. So I don't think that's the efficient way. But is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: You can use `System.currentMilliSeconds()` to get the time spend for each process, and then add it together, no ? You don't care if they aren't sync, compute their own duration separately.

Comment: Thing is from the egde application it may not be sent as soon as it receives data. It may keep it in temporary store if the system is busy and then it will send it when system becomes available. So I can't do it that way

Comment: @Lutzi `currentMilliSeconds` is like a big clock to be used for times >5-1sec, `nanoTime` is more like a good stopwatch to use for the other

Comment: so you want to measure *elapsed* time for each application (some process of it)? `System.nanoTime` is the tool to use

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single database (preferably MongoDB)  and can store currentDateTime() according to the databases. I think that should serve the purpose.